# MongoDB Architecture Optimization: Nested Object List versus Dynamic Collection

Tags: mongodb, optimization

I am currently building a multi-product application using the MEAN stack and I would love to have your feedback on optimising a Mongo Database architecture.

Basically I am building an online course platform, similar - but a lot simpler - to udemy.com, where teachers can create multiple courses and students can then sign up for individual courses. One of the big difference is that when a student signs up for a course, he/she can only access that course. And he/she would have to sign up again to join another course. As there is no relationship between courses.

In a nutshell, the Students Collection must be specific to each course, with unique username per course. So my question is: should I create a dynamic MongoDB Collection for each course? If "course1" is created by a teacher, then a "course1ID-students" collection would also be created. I am using Mongoose so this is quite easy to do but I would just love to have your feedback on dynamic collections. Another option would be to create a single courses collection. Within that collection, add the studentList as an array of object. So a schema similar to:

```
courses: {
    id,
    courseTile,
    studentList: [
        {
            id,
            email,
            password,
            ...
        }],
    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance!